# Rails - convert date string into javascript date object for highcharts

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, highcharts

I'm working on a dashboard app using Rails 3.1.1/Highcharts with several graphs, but am stuck on converting a date string from the rails model into a javascript format that highcharts can accept.

My sample code:

```
<%= @orders.map{ |f| [f.date, f.units.to_f] }.inspect %>
```

Produces this output:

```
[[Fri, 04 Nov 2011, 182.0], [Sun, 06 Nov 2011, 189.0], [Tue, 08 Nov 2011, 178.0], [Thu, 10 Nov 2011, 115.0], [Sat, 12 Nov 2011, 135.0], [Mon, 14 Nov 2011, 120.0], [Thu, 17 Nov 2011, 181.0], [Sun, 20 Nov 2011, 145.0]]
```

I need to have the date format of the array as follows:

```
Date.UTC(2010, 10, 4).
```

Any suggestions on an existing rails/ruby method or how to create a helper?

Comment: In what language do you want to do the conversion? What is the relevance of UTC for dates?

Comment: What is f.date?  A string or a ruby date object?

Comment: The primary use is for Highcharts, so the date conversion needs to be in javascript...but if there is a way to convert in ruby in a model first, then render to js, that works.

Comment: f.date is the column in the order table for when each order is entered...it could be called anything (ex: "purchased_at")

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This probably isn't the best way to do this, but I've been doing:

```
data: <%= @orders.map{ |f| [f.date.to_datetime.to_i, pdd.field_5x5 ] }.inspect %>,
```

...which expresses the date in seconds.

Comment: for highcharts you just need to multiply the date by 1000, because it works in milliseconds. so in the end you would have `data: <%= @orders.map{ |f| [f.date.to_datetime.to_i*1000, pdd.field_5x5 ] }.inspect %>,`
 +1 for making it clear that to_i converts to seconds.